# Does $\frac{d x}{dy}$ indicate that $x=f(y)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Does the expression $\dfrac{d x}{dy}$ indicate that $x=f(y)$ ? Can we compute it even if $y=g(x)$ ?

For example, if $y=g(x)=x^2,$ is $\dfrac{d x}{dy}$ meaningful even though $y=g(x),$ rather than $x=f(y)$ ?

Comment: Typically, yes.

Comment: In a problem where you are being asked something about the derivative it would be a reasonable thing to assume, but you can always have the pointless situation $x = f(z)$ and then say $\frac{dx}{dy} = 0$ is still mathematically correct.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis 

but if $\frac{d x}{dy}=0$ this imply that $x=h(y)=c$ so that must indicate that $x=h(y)$ ?

Comment: @Randall 

so it must imply that $x=g(y)$ and we can't compute $\frac{d x}{dy}$ in case that $y=f(x)$ because it will be meaningless , is that right ?

Comment: Yes, in a way you can say any function depends on any arbitrary variable if you call it it a constant.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis $x=3z^2\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}\equiv0;$ for example, if additionally $z=2y,$ then $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}=12z.$

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis but how can $x=f(z)$ and also $x=g(y)$ at the same time?

Comment: @ryang so according to your example it is a must that $x=g(y)$ in order to compute $dx/dy$ ?

Comment: Yes you are right. If $x$ is a function of $z$, but it then turns out that this was a function of $y$ then the derivatives wont be zero, but this is back in the original case that $x = x(y)$ but it was disguised.

Comment: @amin I didn't say that... P.S. Hope my readability edit is okay. If not, please just roll it back.

Comment: @ryang yes it's better now ,but i'am still confused about the question i'am asking?

Comment: @amin "For example, if $y=g(x)=x^2,$ is $\dfrac{d x}{dy}$ meaningful even though $y=g(x),$ rather than $x=f(y)$ ?"  In this case, then, on $x\in[0,\infty),\;x=\pm\sqrt y,$ so every point where $x$ is positive has two simultaneous values for $\dfrac{d x}{dy}.$

Answer (score 1):

$y=g(x)$ establishes a functional relation between $x$ and $y$, and under some conditions, it can be inverted as $x=g^{-1}(y)$. Hence there is no real difference between $y=g(x)$ and $x=f(y)$.

This said, when the derivatives exist, the following relation holds:

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac1{\dfrac{dy}{dx}}.$$

---

**Illustration:**

For positive $x$ and $y$,

$$y=x^2\iff x=\sqrt y.$$

Then using the common rules of differentiation,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$$

and

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac1{2\sqrt y}=\frac1{2x}.$$

Comment: so in case in $y=f(x)$ :(we define that y is the function in x ) so the only thing that we can compute is $dy/dx$ because $f(x)$ changes with $x$ and in the same case we can't compute $dx/dy$ because the $f(x)$ changes with $x$ not that $x$ that changes with $f(x)$

but in case like $y=x^2$ we don't know what is the function of the other so we can compute $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$, but in case that we've defined $y=f(x)$ we can't compute $dx/dy$ in that case unless we've defined the inverse functio ,is that right ?

Comment: @amin: in all cases we can compute both derivatives.

Comment: but what is the meaning of $dx/dy$ in case that $y=f(x)$ ?

Comment: @amin: I think that you understood nothing of my answer.

Comment: the term $dx/dy$ measure the change in $x$ w.r.t to the change $y$ in case that $y=f(x)$ the variable who controls the change is $x$ not $y$ then how can we measure $dx/dy$ ?

Comment: @amin: this is said in my answer, but you don't want to believe it. You have a wrong understanding of the notation $y=g(x)$.

Comment: the only way i understand the meaning of it in case of the inverse function where $x=f^-1 (y)$

Comment: i know we can compute the both in all cases because they are reciprocals of each other but what i say in case of $y=f(x)$ , $dx/dy$ has no meaning

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, I would hope most authors would provide a little bit of context (e.g. "let $x:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that..." etc.) as it would be very confusing otherwise! However given no additional information, we can still deduce a few things.

The derivative as Leibniz used it was defined in terms of infinitesimals. In this sense, $dy$ and $dx$ were well defined quantities, and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ was actually a fraction, not just notation. By this definition, which is nowadays a nonstandard approach to calculus (though an equally intriguing one), $$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}},$$ as our fraction rules would suggest.

In modern mathematics, infinitesimals have largely been abandoned in the field of analysis (calculus' big brother), and therefore $\frac{d}{dx}$ is really just an alternative notation for the derivative function. Formally, the derivative function takes a differentiable function as an input, and gives its derivative as the output. If we let $D$ be our derivative function, and $f$ be a differentiable function, $f' := D(f)$. By this definition, derivatives only make sense in terms of functions. If $y=f(x)$, we use a little bit of slight of hand, and define $$\frac{dy}{dx} = D(f).$$ Therefore, if we suppose that $y = f(x)$, $\frac{dx}{dy}$ has no defined meaning. Since $x$ is not defined as a function of $y$, we do not have a function to plug into our derivative function $D$, and therefore the notation is meaningless.

It can potentially make sense however when $f^{-1}$ exists, in which case, $x = f^{-1}(y)$, and $\frac{dx}{dy} = D(f^{-1})$. This is not super explicit so I don't like it very much, but yes it does work. Try as an exercise to see what this derivative will equal.

Therefore, by our modern definition, $\frac{dx}{dy}$ only makes sense when $x=f(y)$.

P.S. To Theo Diamantakis (I don't have enough reputation to comment), the case of $x=f(z)$ *could* be defined as you say. Your definition seems to be taking the partial derivative of some implicit function $g(y, z) = f(z)$ with respect to $y$. This seems sensible at first, but it's actually rather stupid to do. It's imprecise and confusing. Instead of doing the above, I would hope that whenever something like this arises in context, the author would be explicit about what all the notations mean, and not randomly take the derivative of $x$ with respect to something other than which it was "defined". It was bad enough that this author swapped $y$ and $x$ in the first place. You can debate all day about what this notation *should* mean, but the reality is that something like that should not happen.

Comment: but if we have an example like $y=x^2$ and we don't know which variable is a function of the other , then the proper way to treat it as a normal relation, can we in this case compute $dx/dy$ and $dy/dx$ ?

Comment: you've defined a function $D$ that takes an input $f$ where ($f$) a differentiable and gives output $f'$ 

but the function is defined as it's graph where a function $f$ is a set of ordered pairs of $(a,f(a))$ but you are saying a function $D$ takes input $f(x)$ and gives output $f'(x)$ and i can't see that a well defined function because there is no graph to define it

Comment: @amin regarding your first comment, convention is that $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$ work how you expect with relations. To be honest I've never put much thought into the formalities of relations so I can't give a great answer.

Comment: @amin Functions are indeed defined as a set of ordered pairs. The ordered pairs of $D$ just so happens to be ordered pairs of functions. A function does not need to be defined using real numbers as inputs and outputs. They can take anything as an input, and anything as an output. Specifically, if we let $X$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, $D$ is a partial function from $X$ to $X$. What this means is that $D(f)$ is itself a function.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by the first comment you've written ?

Answer (score -1):

**In Essence , $dy/dx$ tells us how $y$ changes when $x$ changes , while $dx/dy$ tell us how $x$ changes when $y$ changes.

In general , these are reciprocals.**

"Does $dx/dy$ imply x=f(y) .... not the other way around" : No , It will not imply $x=f(y)$ nor will it imply $y=g(x)$ , though these are the common cases in high school introductory texts. It DOES imply that the 2 variables are inter-related , not which variable is Independent & which variable is Dependant.

More-over , there are not 2 Possibilities , **there is a third Possibility** , which is more general :
$h(x,y)=0$
Even in that case , we can calculate $dy/dx$ & $dx/dy$ , which will neither imply $y=f(x)$ nor imply $x=g(y)$. It DOES tell us that the variables are inter-related , with $h(x,y)=0$ in most general terms. In certain cases , it might get simplified.

**Case 3 $h(x,y)=0$** :

Consider $h(X,Y) = Y + \sin Y - X \cos X = 0$
Plot given by wolfram :
[image: PLOT]

We can calculate (by using rules of Differentiation) that :
$dy/dx + \cos Y dy/dx - \cos X + X \sin X = 0$
which gives us
$dy/dx = (\cos X - X \sin X)/(1 + \cos Y) \tag{1}$
$dx/dy = (1 + \cos Y)/(\cos X - X \sin X) \tag{2}$

Here (1) & (2) are Entirely Equivalent , though it will neither imply $y=f(x)$ nor imply $x=g(y)$ , where we know that $h(x,y)=0$

**Case 1 $y=f(x)$ (which is Equivalent to Case 2 $x = y(x)$ ) :**

Consider easier case :
$y = e^{+9x}$
$dy/dx = 9e^{+9x} \tag{3}$
$dx/dy = e^{-9x}/9 \tag{4}$
It can be changed to
$x = (\log y)/9$
$dx/dx = 1/9y \tag{5}$
$dy/dx = 9y \tag{6}$
Here (3) , (4) , (5) , (6) are all Entirely Equivalent.
We have calculated both $dy/dx$ & $dx/dy$ in 2 variations each , though we can not know which is Independent variable & which is Dependent variable.

**Summary : In all these Cases , we can & we are able to calculate both $dy/dx$ & $dx/dy$ . . . . .

It tell us how one variable changes when the other variable changes , nothing less , nothing more.**

Comment: Those who are inclined to down-vote , may I know what is wrong with this Answer ?

Comment: This happens all the time, many people downvote for unclear reasons. You could flag the answer and write "Targeted downvote" under "in need of moderator intervention". Other than that, just ignore the downvotes. +1 for your excellent answer!

Comment: Oh , I was not aware of "Targeted downvote" , thank you for the tip & for your up-vote & for your gentle thoughts about the matter !

Comment: so in case in $y=f(x)$ :(we define that $y$ is the function in $x$) so the only thing that we can compute is $dy/dx$ because $f(x$) changes with $x$ and in the same case we can't compute $dx/d$y because the $f(x)$ changes with $x$ not that $x$ that changes with $f(x)$, but in case like $y=x^2$ we don't know what is the function of the other so we can compute $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$, but in case that we've defined $y=f(x)$ we can't compute $dx/dy$ in that case unless we've defined the inverse function ,is that right ?

Comment: We can ALWAYS compute $"dy/dx"$ AND $"dx/dy"$ , which are reciprocals in general. @amin

Comment: @Prem 
but what is the meaning of $dx/dy$ in case that $y=f(x)$ ?

Comment: It indicates how $x$ changes with a change in $y$. [[1]] You can think about it like reciprocal : $y=ax+b$ gives $dy/dx=a$ , hence $dx/dy=1/a$ [[2]] You can alternately think in terms of Inverse function : $y=ax+b$ gives $x=(y-b)/a$ , hence $dx/dy=1/a$ , Exactly Equivalent @amin

Comment: i understand what you're saying but in case where $y=f(x)$, i know that we can compute $dx/dy$,but you say that it indicates how $x$ changes with a change in $y$ ,but the case that y changes with x not that x changes with y

Comment: That is necessary in Physical Systems when we have (or want) cause-&-effect relationship between Independent variable & Dependent variable , Eg velocity $v$ "at" time $t$. **In Mathematics , we have no such restriction !** We can easily talk about $t$ "changing with" $v$ ! @amin

Comment: @Prem I understand that, but even in math when talking about changes we must clarify which variable change by the other , we can say that $dx/dy$ meaningful in case of the inverse function and the same as $v$ and $t$

Comment: That was why I introduced you to Case 3 , where there is no Independent variable , with both variables Depending on each other in $h(x,y)=0$ , where we will have $dy/dx$ & $dx/dy$. Case 3 is very general & It covers Case 1 via Simple transformation : $y=f(x)$ is Equivalent to $y-f(x)=0=h((x,y)$ .... Similarly Case 2 $x=g(y)$ becomes Equivalent to $x-g(y)=0=h((x,y)$ .... Hence in all Cases , we have 2 inter-related variables , hence we have both $dy/dx$ & $dx/dy$ .... @amin

Comment: @prem I understand that in case 3 but I want to be assured of something, in case 1 where y=f(x) ,is there even a meaning for $dx/dy$  ?i'am talking about case 1 only

Comment: Case 1 :: $y=f(x)$ :: Is there a meaning to $dx/dy$ ? Yes !! Is it valid ? Yes !! @amin